# SQL statements to sum unique pairs of fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table like this:

```
  country  |city     |sales | old
  -------------------------------
    USA    | New York|  100 |   1
    USA    | New York|  200 |   0
    USA    | Miami   |   50 |   1
    Canada | Toronto |   20 |   0
    Canada | Toronto |  100 |   0
```

I would like to do 2 things:

1) I want to produce a result like this, sum of all sales on unique country-city pairs:

```
  country  |city     |sales|
  --------------------------
    USA    | New York|  300|
    USA    | Miami   |   50|
    Canada | Toronto |  120|
```

2) I want to produce a result like this, sum of all sales on unique country-city pairs on new accounts only (old=0)

```
  country  |city     |sales|
  --------------------------
    USA    | New York|  200|
    Canada | Toronto |  120|
```

What 2 SQL statements do I need for this? It is currently beyond my new-to SQL skills...

p.s. if I wanted to do the opposite of #2, sum the old accounts (so old != 0), then how would I change the SQL statement for #2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it all in one query by using CASE statements (The SQL version of IF..THEN).

```
SELECT  Country
        ,City
        ,SUM(Sales) as Tot_Sales 
        ,SUM( CASE WHEN Old = 0 THEN 0 ELSE Sales END) as New_Sales
        ,SUM( CASE WHEN Old = 1 THEN 0 ELSE Sales END) as Old_Sales
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY
        Country
        ,City
```

If you want a query just for the old sales, it would look like this. For New Sales, you would just change the WHERE condition.

```
SELECT  Country
        ,City
        ,SUM(Sales) as Sales 
FROM    YourTable
WHERE   Old = 1
GROUP BY
        Country
        ,City
```

Answer (score 1):

answer 1:

```
SELECT  Country
        ,City
        ,SUM(Sales) as Sales 
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY
        Country
        ,City
```

answer2:

```
SELECT  Country
        ,City
        ,SUM(Sales) as Sales 
FROM    YourTable
WHERE   Old = 1
GROUP BY
        Country
        ,City
```